# How to use vscode debugger with Next.js

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, next.js, vscode-debugger

I am trying to use next.js with vs code debugger but it doesn't work. Also, is there anyone able to make it work? I am using graphql and apollo.

I tried official documetation > [Official Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging)

I tried dev.to blog post.> [Dev.to Post](https://dev.to/vvo/5-steps-to-debugging-next-js-node-js-from-vscode-or-chrome-devtools-497o)

I tried open github issue > [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/issues/227)